# How to mount an encrypted partition image from an external drive?

Tags: mount, ecryptfs

I created a partition image (120GB Block Device /dev/ubuntu-vg/root Ext4) and put it on an external hard-drive.
I connected the disk to my other computer and I opened the image with DiskImageMounter and navigated to the `/media/user/.../home/user` dir which contains a README and an icon Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop.

Pressing the icon makes a window pop up and dissapears again right away.
Then I ran `ecryptfs-mount-private` in the terminal, which doesn't give any output (success).

I assume this doesn't work because the command is assuming the encrypted files to be in `~/.Private` which is not the same as `/media/user/.../home/user/.Private`

Is there a simple way to access the directory?
Something like: `$ecrypt-mount-thisdir dir`

(I don't want to copy, restore permanently or delete anything).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use

> `ecryptfs-recover-private` - find and mount any encrypted private directories
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          `ecryptfs-recover-private [--rw] [encrypted private dir]`
>
> DESCRIPTION
>   This  utility  is  intended  to  help  eCryptfs recover data from their encrypted home or
>          encrypted private partitions.  It is useful to run this from  a  LiveISO  or  a  recovery
>          image.   It  must  run  under  sudo(8)  or  with  root permission, in order to search the
>          filesystem and perform the mounts.

Telling it which directory to decrypt is optional too, it will search everywhere if it's omitted (but that could be pretty slow).

It's actually a shell script, so you could see  it yourself (or run manually if you desired) with

```
less `which ecryptfs-recover-private`
```